# How can I make AndroidX the default library for new Android projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

Google now recommends using the AndroidX libraries over the older support libraries ([read here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions)), yet each time I start a new Android project in Android studio, it defaults to the support libraries dependencies. Since AndroidX is what is recommended, I'm guessing there must be some way to default to AndroidX?

Right now I need to manually configure the gradle.properties file for each new project, as below

From the [AndroidX Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx):

> If you want to use AndroidX in a new project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher and set both of the following Android Gradle plugin flags to true in your gradle.properties file.
>     android.useAndroidX: When set to true, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.
>   android.enableJetifier: When set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

Is there a way to make Android Studio use only AndroidX by default?

Comment: have you tried just making a new project and checking what the options are ? mine is making them android X by default ?

Comment: Very low effort question. You can find the setting right in the project creation wizard of Android Studio

Comment: @a_local_nobody : Yes I did. And mine was including the support.v7 libraries. It took me quite some time to figure out that not only do you have to change the dependencies in the app gradle but also in the gradle.settings. So the question.

Comment: In that case it's still a low effort question. You can see this in the project creation wizard of Android Studio

Comment: I'm voting to close this questions as off-topic. Asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a recommendation for a book, tool etc. The question was about Android best practices (Using the androidX implementation) . And it is a common problem that other users will face. I have made changes to the original question though. If you still feel its off-topic feel free to do the needful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndroidX is enabled by default. In fact, in the latest version of Android Studio, you don't even have the option to deselect the AndroidX dependencies. See here:

[image: Sample Project]

The `androidx.*` artifacts are already selected. If your Android Studio doesn't support this, try updating it or installing it again. Make sure to not import the older preferences from your IDE. It will refresh your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

when u create any new project in android studio in the latest version then it will by default open with androidX library.